# NHibernate - When FlushMode is given as Never and if I close the session by session.Close(), will the changes be sent to server?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

If I have the FlushMode as Never and if I do a session.Close() will the changes be persisted to the database?

Or do we have to explicitly say session.Flush() before session.Close()?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close() never flushes for you (whether you have FlushMode=Never or not), and even if it did, you shouldn't depend on that.

See: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing

Comment: 1.2 was a long time ago, the current docs are at: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing